# VirtualDub can't access a capturing device but if I put VD into SandBoxie it does. Why?

Tags: windows, drivers, virtualdub, sandboxie

I have a Windows 10 machine and a video capturing USB device called EasyCap which lets you convert analog video and audio signals into digital files. The device's driver was installed by OS automatically and looks OK in its properties.

Whenever I try to access this device in VirtualDub it gives me an error "VirtualDub cannot connect to the desired capture driver". But if I put VirtualDub into Sandboxie (pseudo-virtual machine which uses copies of actual resources of your OS) it works flawlessly.

I'm not seeking for a solution of my problem but I really want to understand what can cause this problem and how this particular part of Windows works. If you need any more details ask in comments please and I will provide them. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sandboxie is not considered a pseudo-virtual machine.  Sandboxie has absolutely no virtualization or hypervisor capabilities.  One of the reasons it could work is because the device is being used by a different application and/or I have in the past had issues with a camera not working due to an ASUS USB charging driver being installed.  You can confirm this is the case by using an actual virtual machine, if it works, then you know you have a conflicting driver.  The reason it would work is due to how Sandboxie works

Comment: Wow thanks! Is there a way to detect what driver or application causes the conflict?

Comment: Boot into a minimal configuration.  You can use Autoruns and make sure only the drivers that are absolutely required are loaded.  You can then also manually make sure only a bare minimum of the startup applications are started.  If it this ends up working you have verified there is a conflict that exists

Comment: Woah I didn't know you can disable entries in Autoruns. Welp, I disabled literally everything in it except that capturing device driver and still got that error.

Comment: So it isn't an application.  What about the drivers?  That is how I found out that the ASUS USB drivers for my motherboard would prevent my USB camera from working on the desktop version of Skype (see my question on that subject if you want to know more)

Comment: I meant I disabled EVERYTHING in Autoruns, even drivers. I rebooted into 1024x768 or so because even GPU drivers were off and still the same error though the capturing device was present in the device manager and was ok in its properties' status.